# Not understanding the meaning of the song Resurrecting by Elevation Worship

Tags: hymns

There is a song by **Elevation Worship** named **Resurrecting**. As I am not a Christian, I failed to understand some of these lines:

> Our God is alive
>   The tomb with soldiers watched in vain
>   was borrowed for three days
>   HIS body there would not remain
>   Our God has robbed the grave

Can anybody explain me these lines? Thanks.

Comment: The lines are talking about the brief time Jesus was dead and buried in a tomb before he came back to life. Is there anything specific in those lines that you'd like more information about?

Comment: I am actually not understanding the ethical meaning of these lines. As ''was borrowed for three days'', what is actually meant, why 3 days, I don't know. And "Our God has robbed the grave", what does it actually mean??

Comment: Jesus died and was buried on Friday, and rose again on Sunday, which is the three days. The tomb was "borrowed" because when Jesus came back to life he didn't need it any more. The owner who donated it (a guy named Joseph) could use it again for someone else in his family if he wanted. And it's as if the grave was robbed because what should have belonged to it, and what should have belong to death, Jesus, was taken away and given back to life.

Comment: From your questions it sounds like you're missing a basic familarity with the Jesus story, so I'd recommend you read one of his biographies, written by a follower of his named Mark. [Here's the first chapter](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+1&version=NIV), and you can read the rest with the arrows to the right. The whole biography should take less than 2 hours to read.

Comment: Yes, I haven't read the biography of Jesus. Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Meanwhile, welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lyrics are about the resurrection of Jesus Christ.

> Our God is alive

Our God, Jesus, is not dead, even though he was killed, but is alive because he rose from the dead.

> The tomb with soldiers watched in vain

After bring crucified, the body of Jesus was placed in a tomb and soldiers were placed on guard at it. However Jesus did arise, and the soldiers were unable to prevent it.

> was borrowed for three days.

Jesus was laid in a tomb, but after three days rose again. The tomb was not needed after that - it was only borrowed, not kept permanently.

> His body there would not remain
>
> our God has robbed the grave

God, like a grave robber, has taken the body out of the grave - not by stealing it, but because he has the power to do so. Moreover he does the same for all of us, in that he will resurrect us all in due time - 'cheating' the enemy of the punishment that we deserve for our sins, which is death - the ultimate 'robbing' of the ultimate grave.

It is possible to get into trouble by taking that last line as too literal and exact a theological statement. God is not being deceitful or dishonest in 'robbing' the grave. It's a song lyric, not a doctrinal statement.